# thanos sorting problem from codeforces. Error :TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, sorting, non-type

i am new to programming.pls suggest other issues in my program, which will improve my programming skills

Thanos sort is a supervillain sorting algorithm, which works as follows: if the array is not sorted, snap your fingers* to remove the first or the second half of the items, and repeat the process.

Given an input array, what is the size of the longest sorted array you can obtain from it using Thanos sort?

*Infinity Gauntlet required.

Input
The first line of input contains a single number n (1≤n≤16) — the size of the array. n is guaranteed to be a power of 2.

The second line of input contains n space-separated integers ai (1≤ai≤100) — the elements of the array.

Output
Return the maximal length of a sorted array you can obtain using Thanos sort. The elements of the array have to be sorted in non-decreasing order.

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType on the line with comment error'

```
def find():
    a = int(input())
    if a%2==0 and a<=16 and a>=1:
        x = input()
        l = x.split()
        p= lcheck(l)
        r = rcheck(l)
        if p < r: # error
            return r
        else:
            return p

    else:
        print("enter the array length correctly")
        find()
def lcheck(l):
    n = len(l)
    m= sorted(l)
    if  l==m:
        return len(l)
    else:
        n=n//2
        l=l[:n]
        if len(l)>1:
            lcheck(l)
        else:
            return 1  
def rcheck(l):
    n = len(l)
    m= sorted(l)
    if  l==m:
        return len(l)
    else:
        n=n//2
        l=l[n+1:]
        if len(l)>1:
            rcheck(l)
        else:
            return 1
def splitint(x):
    l = x.split()
    l = list(map(int,l))
    return l
find()
```

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
     42     l = list(map(int,l))
     43     return l
---> 44 find()

```
<ipython-input-15-4486e758ce8e> in find()
      6         p= lcheck(l)
      7         r = rcheck(l)
----> 8         if p < r: # error
      9             return r
     10         else:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please share where your traceback - which line of code produces the error. Also, please add a link to the problem at codeforce.

Comment: http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1145/A

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-4486e758ce8e> in <module>
     42     l = list(map(int,l))
     43     return l
---> 44 find()

<ipython-input-15-4486e758ce8e> in find()
      6         p= lcheck(l)
      7         r = rcheck(l)
----> 8         if p < r: # error
      9             return r
     10         else:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning the result of the recursive lcheck and rcheck calls (no return -> you get a None), change it to something like:

```
if len(l)>1:
    return lcheck(l)
else:
    return 1
```

Further tips:

- lcheck and rcheck share most of their code, which is undesirable
- you can use max(p, r)
- use descriptive variable names, not just single letters (sometimes it's fine)

Answer (score 0):

Your code will fail the below test case:

16

78 16 40 90 4 13 99 19 41 47 50 68 71 79 96 76

Below is the working code which you may want to try:

```
def lcheck(a):
    if a == sorted(a):
        return len(a)
    else:
        new_a = a[:len(a)//2]
        if len(new_a) > 1:
            if lcheck(new_a) >= rcheck(new_a):
                return lcheck(new_a)
            else:
                return rcheck(new_a)
        else:
            return 1

def rcheck(a):
    if a == sorted(a):
        return len(a)
    else:
        new_a = a[len(a)//2:]
        if len(new_a) > 1:
            if lcheck(new_a) >= rcheck(new_a):
                return lcheck(new_a)
            else:
                return rcheck(new_a)
        else:
            return 1

if __name__=="__main__":
    n = int(input())
    a = list(map(int, input().split()))
    if lcheck(a) >= rcheck(a):
        print(lcheck(a))
    else:
        print(rcheck(a))
```